# axios can not get the respones data

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vue.js

The purpose of this code is to get the Alipay order number and create the Alipay order. First, we use the post method to request the created order number from the backend, and then use the obtained order number to request payment from Alipay using the GET method.

Because the order number is required in the GET method, I nest the GET request after the POST.

When the browser simulates the APP running, the res can be obtained, but the res in `axios.get` in the APP is null.

My project is vue embedded in the APP, what should I do?

```
 axios.post(cloud_order, params, this.headers).then((res) => {
            if (!res.code) {
              this.orderId = res.data.order_no;
              if (window.JSInterface) {
                //android
                window.JSInterface.toPay(this.orderId, this.money, this.payType);
              } else {
                //ios
                let params = {
                  order_no: this.orderId,
                  subject: this.money,
                };
                axios.get(aliPay_ez, params, this.headers).then((res) => {
                  this.test.push(1);
                  this.test.push(res);
                  if (!res.code) {
                    let routerData = this.$router.resolve({
                      path: "/camera/applyText",
                      query: { htmls: res.data.order_info },
                    });
                    this.htmls = res.data.order_info;
                    const div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = this.htmls;
                    document.body.appendChild(div);
                    document.forms[0].submit();
                  } else {
                    this.$toast(res.message);
                  }
                });
              }
            } else {
              this.$toast(res.message);
            }
          });
```

Comment: POST is not null  ,  GET is null

Comment: not,android also

Comment: No error occurred in this process, so the catch error couldn't get anything. I used a packet capture tool on my mobile phone to capture the data returned by the background. The data was normal, but the front end did not get the res. The res in the obtained package is normal, but the front end got a "correct" null

Comment: I mean, my VUE project is running on Android and IOS platforms, embedded in APP, so browsers on Android and IOS platforms cannot get this res，thanks for anwser :)

Comment: I'm sorry, because the Android APP comes with its own payment method, so you only need to create an order number, but I tested it, and the GET method was added to the Android, and I still didn't get the RES.

Comment: This is not the case. The requested API interface returned data, and the packet was captured, but obviously the front-end did not obtain the correct data. The reason why it is said that "incorrect data was obtained" is because if the API does not return, or the front-end does not After receiving the returned data, res will be undefind instead of null

Comment: Are you able to get this working in for example Postman or another HTTP client?

Comment: sure,postman show the right RES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deal, it is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin' problem